# Webpack with Babel lazy load module using ES6 recommended Import() approach not working

Tags: import, webpack, ecmascript-6, lazy-loading, babeljs

I'm trying to do code splitting and lazy loading with webpack using the [import() method](https://webpack.js.org/api/module-methods/#import-)

```
import('./myLazyModule').then(function(module) {
    // do something with module.myLazyModule
}
```

I'm getting

> 'import' and 'export' may only appear at the top level

Note top level imports are working fine, i'm just getting an issue when I try and using the dynamic variant of import()

```
var path = require('path');

module.exports = {
    entry: {
        main: "./src/app/app.module.js",
    },
    output: {
        path: path.resolve(__dirname, "dist"),
        filename: "[name]-application.js"
    },
    module: {
        rules: [
            {
                test: /\.js$/,
                use: [{
                    loader: 'babel-loader',
                    query: {
                        presets: ['es2015']
                    }
                }]
            }
        ]
    },
    resolve : {
        modules : [
            'node_modules',
            'bower_components'
        ]
    },
    devtool : "source-map"
}
```

EDIT:

If I change it so the syntax reads, it works.... but the chunk comments don't work to label the bundle. I'm confused because the documentation says the the following is depreciated.

> The use of System.import in webpack did not fit the proposed spec, so
>   it was deprecated in webpack 2.1.0-beta.28 in favor of import().

```
System.import('./myLazyModule').then(function(module) {
    // do something with module.myLazyModule
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need the plugin `syntax-dynamic-import` to be able to use the `import()` function with Babel.

Install it with:

```
npm install --save-dev @babel/plugin-syntax-dynamic-import
```

And add it to your plugins:

```
{
    presets: ['es2015'],
    plugins: ['@babel/plugin-syntax-dynamic-import']
}
```